# Cascading Style Sheet positioning trouble

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` which contains five img tags.
Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="Images/1.jpg"/>
        <img src="Images/2.jpg"/>
        <img src="Images/3.jpg"/>
        <img src="Images/4.jpg"/>           
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the stylesheet:

```
img
{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.container
{
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

When I'm resizing the browser window everything got messed up.

This is the normal form
[image]

This is the form after resizing

[image]

I want pictures to stay in their places.
How can i fix this?

Comment: You might want to do a bit of research on responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to your `.container` div:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:10px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:relative and try using float:left or center

Answer (score 0):

Give width of .container as pixels not as %. If you have 4 div give width(.container) as 1000px(4*250).